# Getting selected item from a JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

How do I get the selected item from a `TableView` in JavaFX?

I am currently using

```
ObservableList selectedItems = taview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

but that does not return me the one selected item in the selection model.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Ok, lets say you have a data model class named `Person`. This way:

```
Person person = taview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(person.getName());
```

Note that `TableView` must take a `Person` as a type argument to avoid casting:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> taview;
```

or

```
TableView<Person> taview = new TableView<>();
```

when your row is selected, you will return one `Person` instance. Then do what ever you want with that instance.

Answer (score 9):

```
    tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
        if(tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) 
        {    
           TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableview.getSelectionModel();
           ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
           TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
           Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
           System.out.println("Selected Value" + val);
         }
         }
     });
```

Using this code you can get the selected value from JAVAFX TABLEVIEW Cell.

Thanks..

Comment: this code worked for me. But it works only when I select some another row. How do I run this code everytime a tablecell is selected even if the same row is selected

Comment: There is any way to get the mouse coordinate inside this listener to show something like a popup menu?

Answer (score 3):

For single item selection...

```
Product p = taview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(p.getName());
```

For multiple item selection...

```
ArrayList<Product> p = new ArrayList<>(taview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
for (Product res : p) {     
    System.out.println(res.getName());      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@pranishres

Here is my try for a cell selection change listener (even if row doesn’t change), inspired by @Java Man's code:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
ObservableList selectedCells = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();

selectedCells.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change c) {
        TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
        Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(tablePosition.getRow());
        System.out.println("Selected Value" + val);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get data from tableview like that

For One ItemSelection

```
`tableview_obj.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().yourgetterobjectname`
```

and Mulltiple Item Selection

`tableview_obj.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().get(indexNo).yourgetterobjectname`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method maybe it works for you

```
ObservableList rowList = (ObservableList) tblView.getItems().get(getIndex());
```

and for the call method will be like that

```
String email = rowList.get(1).toString();
String contact = rowList.get(2).toString();
String name= rowList.get(0).toString();
```

Comment: Add some description, on your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Object row2 = tableEmployees.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().get(0);
        String ordre = row2.toString().split(",")[0].substring(1);
        System.out.println("Ordre N " + ordre);
```

well this is the best solution you can found it ever

Answer (score -2):

if you have a Bean class named Employee.

```
Employee employee= tblView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
txtEmployeeName.setText(employee.getName());
```